# Getting an error code from a method that I shouldn't get

Tags: c#, debugging

I seem to be miscalling or misusing code in these two sections of my code. I understand what is causing the program to give me the IsOperator error message when I debug it. The odd thing is that the + operator works but none of the others do.

```
public bool IsValidData()
{  
    return
        IsPresent(txtOperand1, "Operand 1") &&
        IsDecimal(txtOperand1, "Operand 1") &&
        IsWithinRange(txtOperand1, "Operand 1", 0, 1000000) &&

        IsPresent(txtOperator, "Operator") &&
        IsOperator(txtOperator, "+, -, *, /") &&

        IsPresent(txtOperand2, "Operand 2") &&
        IsDecimal(txtOperand2, "Operand 2") &&
        IsWithinRange(txtOperand2, "Operand 2", 0, 1000000);
}

public bool IsOperator(TextBox textBox, string operators)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string s in operators.Split(new char[] { ',' }))
        {
            if (textBox.Text.Trim() == s)
                return true;
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("The operator must be a valid operator: +,-, *, /", "name");
        }
        return true;

    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        txtOperator.Focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception that you are immediately catching, and then returning false inside the exception handler? Why not just return false directly, without throwing the exception?

Comment: it would be very helpful if you post the exact error message

Comment: Well it says "The operator must be a valid operator: +,-,*,/                       Parameter name: name

Comment: @bansi the error message OP refers to is the one OP's code is generating itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your operators list contains spaces:

```
"+, -, *, /"
```

This is causing the unexpected behaviour. Try:

```
"+,-,*,/"
```

Or, defensively trim the `s` variable...

You are trimming the text input, but not the operator you compare it to, so `if (textBox.Text.Trim() == s)` will never be true if `s` contains a space.

Also, you are checking the text against a list of operators - it will also fail if it doesn't match the *first* operator, because as soon as that comparison fails, you throw the Argument Exception.

For example, your text box contains `*`, your first operator is `+`:

```
if ("*" == "+") // FAIL
```

My suggested edit - fail only after you check them all:

```
    foreach (string s in operators.Split(new char[] { ',' }))
    {
        if (textBox.Text.Trim() == s.Trim()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show("The operator must be a valid operator: " + operators);
    txtOperator.Focus();
    return false;
```

Comment: Originally the operators weren't spaced. I tried to space them to see if that fixed the behavior. What do you mean by defensively trimming the s variable?

Comment: This is what Steve means: `if (textBox.Text.Trim() == s.Trim())`

Comment: Thanks @CharlieKilian - I've added a couple of extra points to clarify that.

Comment: Right that makes sense. How would I call it differently or change my calling so it wasn't throwing the exception like that? I had it where it went through a list of all 4 operators to check validity but I couldn't figure out how to not call 6 parameters

Comment: Thank you a lot Steve. Just saved my assignment :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this.

```
public bool IsOperator(TextBox textBox, string operators)
{
    string[] operatorArray = operators.Split(new char[] { ',' });
    if (Array.IndexOf(operatorArray, textBox.Text.Trim()) >= 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("The operator must be a valid operator: +,-, *, /");
        textBox.Focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

*Note:* The operators must be like "+,-,*,/" spaces embedded in the operator string may break this function.

Comment: Unless the textbox equals every operator, this will error - within the loop the textbox is compared in turn to `+` then `-` then `/` then `*` - it isn't going to be equal to more than one of these :)

Comment: You should check @SteveFenton's answer, it is explained better.

Comment: I changed my solution to use `Array.IndexOf` instead of `foreach` loop